# How do I set a DateTimeField to zero in Django?

Tags: django

I want to create an object with a DateTime of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` so when I check dates in ASC order, new objects are checked first.

Comment: Why can't you use null value in database?

Comment: @GwynBleidD Do null values come first in ASC?

Comment: Yes, by default they come first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless the date `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is actually meaningful to you, you shouldn't use it as a "special" value. You should use NULL instead e.g.

However, I don't think what's been said in the comments about NULLs coming out first by default in an ascending sort is true, because, let's try with a model like this:

```
class Log(Model):                                                                                                           
    timestamp = DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)                                                                      

    def __str__(self):                                                                                                      
        return str(self.timestamp)
```

I created some objects of that class:

```
In [21]: Log.objects.all()
Out[21]: [<Log: None>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:33:17.464426>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:35:52.313617>, <Log: None>]
```

The above doesn't sort, so they come out in their cardinal order in the database.

Here's an ASC sort:

```
In [22]: Log.objects.order_by('timestamp')                                                                                  
Out[22]: [<Log: 2015-12-28 12:33:17.464426>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:35:52.313617>, <Log: None>, <Log: None>]
```

So as you can see, the NULLs are coming out last in my ASC sort. I am using PostgreSQL for this test.

Here's a DSC sort:

```
In [23]: Log.objects.order_by('-timestamp')
Out[23]: [<Log: None>, <Log: None>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:35:52.313617>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:33:17.464426>]
```

However you can use `extra()` to explicitly specify how you want to sort the NULLs:

```
In [24]: Log.objects.extra(select={'timestamp_is_null': "timestamp is NULL"}, order_by=['-timestamp_is_null', 'timestamp'])
Out[24]: [<Log: None>, <Log: None>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:33:17.464426>, <Log: 2015-12-28 12:35:52.313617>]
```

Here's a more readable of my snippet

```
Log.objects.extra(
    select={'timestamp_is_null': "timestamp is NULL"},
    order_by=['-timestamp_is_null', 'timestamp']
)
```

Versions for this test:

- PostgreSQL 9.4.5
- Django 1.8.4

Comment: Words "you should use" are great. Unfortunately there are a lot of legacy systems, that have scheme with "0000-00-00".

Answer (score 3):

For `django 1.9` use following field:

```
from django.db import models  

class NullDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        # Casts datetimes into the format expected by the backend
        if not prepared:
            value = self.get_prep_value(value)

        # Use zeroed datetime instead of NULL
        if value is None:
            return  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        else:
            return connection.ops.adapt_datetimefield_value(value)
```

Based on django DateTimeField [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1435).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the "epoch":

epoch   date, timestamp 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00 (Unix system time zero)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Please make your answer more detailed.

Comment: Thats really as detailed as it gets but you can learn more about Unix epoch here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time